# Use PHP to extract specific string data

Tags: php, regex

The iframe is assigned to a variable $string. I want extract the texts between embed/ and ?rel in the iframes src. So i would be looking for this code sL-2oYAI35o

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sL-2oYAI35o?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Would I need to use a php substr function or regex? I cant use the regular substring because the start value may differ.

Comment: You should use regex. I don't see an embed or rel tag in the question. Can you post the whole string?

Comment: Sorry the embed is in the iframes src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/sL-2oYAI35o?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

preg_match('`embed/(.+)\?rel`i', $text, $matches);
$code = (!empty($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works.

```
$string = preg_replace('/embed.*\?rel/', 'embed?rel', $string);
```

**Edit** thanks to  @Orangepill

```
$string = preg_replace('/embed(.*)\?rel/', 'embed?rel', $string);
```

**Edit 2** I tested it and it works identically with or without the capture group.

Comment: Its removing the embed code alright but not assigning it to the new $string variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try it with the most recent edit, where it begins with the variable assignment?

Comment: Preg_match with the same pattern but put a capture group around the `.*`

Comment: Works identically with or without capture group, I added it to edit though just inc ase others find that works for them.